# What CompSci concepts have been used in conlanging?

Tags: conlang-creation

I am looking for things in the vein of the use of [run-length encoding](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/a/1401/3888) in representing arbitrarily large integers in a Haskell-based conlang.

An example might be tree data structure based punctuation in a writing system (Lispy), a language in which sentence ends are signaled not by structure but by an explicit stop word (like a C-style language's semi-colon), or a language in which there are labels (explicitly or implicitly) assigned to each sentence, which can be used to refer to that sentence (assembly or BASIC-like).

Could someone share some examples of how CS ideas are used in conlanging?

Comment: ‘Haskell-based conlang’? Interesting; I’ve been pondering similar concepts for a while. Do you have any more information I can read about it?

Comment: The linked question has it: "https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/how-should-my-conlang-enable-arbitrarily-large-integers-to-be-said?noredirect=1&lq=1"

Comment: Ah, thanks! Just FYI, [Leksah](http://www.leksah.org/index.html) has already been used as the name of a Haskell IDE.

Comment: Also, to answer the question, the major example I’m aware of is the stack-based conlang [Fith](https://dedalvs.com/smileys/2019.html). But I’d prefer to hold off on making an actual answer until I find some more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples of conlangs which use CS concepts include

- [Fith](https://dedalvs.com/smileys/2019.html/), as pointed out to me by @bradrn in the comments of this question. It is a stack-based conlang, similar conceptually to forth, or [min](https://min-lang.org/about/). It is spoken by "a race of centaur-like marsupials" known as Fithians.
- [Shallow Fith](https://www.frathwiki.com/Shallow_Fith/), which is intended as a human speak-able subset of [Fith](https://dedalvs.com/smileys/2019.html/), devised to allow Fithians and humans to communicate.
- The conlang from [this question](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/how-should-my-conlang-enable-arbitrarily-large-integers-to-be-said?/), Leksah. It is a functional conlang, inspired by Haskell,  which was created for a world-building project. Leksah has functions, which act similarly to verbs, a function application word, and literals, which act somewhat like nouns.

Edit:

I am in the process of creating an as-yet unpublished conlang with a system of pattern matching with pronouns.
For example, `The red horse is friends with the black dog. The red <third-person pronoun> is much bigger than the black <third-person pronoun>`, would mean that

1. The red horse and black dog are friends.
2. The red horse is much bigger than the black dog.